# quick javascript function help

Tags: javascript

I have this function, and I want to pass a variable (z) to the OnClick event of an image.

I have this:

```
for (z=1; z<img_src.length; z++){
    path_th_img= 'ad_images/'+category+'/'+'thumbs/'+img_src[z];
    document.getElementById("thumb_pic_div").innerHTML += "<img src='"+path_th_img+"' class='shadow2' style='margin:7px;' onclick='imageShow(z);'>";
            }
```

img_src.lengt is in this case 4... So no matter which of the three images I click, the nr 4 gets passed on... ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Using `document.getElementById(el).innerHTML += "..."` in a for loop is very inefficient because you are invoking the HTML parser many times.  It's better to assign the HTML to a variable and then apply the variable to the innerHTML property once after the loop has finished, thus invoking the parser only once.  Just a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass the value of z in your string

```
for (z=1; z<img_src.length; z++) {
    path_th_img= 'ad_images/'+category+'/'+'thumbs/'+img_src[z];
    document.getElementById("thumb_pic_div").innerHTML += 
    "<img src='"+path_th_img+"' class='shadow2' style='margin:7px;' onclick='imageShow("+z+");'>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Shouldn't this:

```
onclick='imageShow(z);'
```

be something like this:

```
onclick='imageShow(' + z + ');'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the DOM, *properly*.

```
for (var z = 1, l = img_src.length; z < l; ++z) {

    var new_img = document.createElement('img');

    new_img.src = 'ad_images/' + category+'/' + 'thumbs/' + img_src[z];
    new_img.onclick = (function(z){
        return function() {
            imageShow(z);
        };
    })(z);
    new_img.style.margin = '7px';

    document.getElementById("thumb_pic_div").appendChild(new_img);

}
```

Comment: Not sure, but +1 from me for suggesting using the DOM.  It's much more efficient than invoking the HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line...

```
document.getElementById("thumb_pic_div").innerHTML += "<img src='"+path_th_img+"' class='shadow2' style='margin:7px;' onclick='imageShow(z);'>";
```

To this...

```
document.getElementById("thumb_pic_div").innerHTML += "<img src='"+path_th_img+"' class='shadow2' style='margin:7px;' onclick='imageShow("+z+");'>";
```